When I use Seeding in .NET Core app, Only DB Schema Migrates without the dummy data I added before
I expect to see the entered data in the SQL database, only migrations applied without the entered data for testing purposes
This is an example of data seeding, I added real IDs of the Categories to keep the relation reliable between products and categories
I'm using IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> not OnModelCreating in the DbContext
    public class CategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

            builder.Property(p => p.Name)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.HasMany(p => p.Products)
                   .WithOne(p => p.Category)
                   .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            var categories = new List<Category> {

            new Category
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("bdafc3c9-abe6-4ac5-bdb6-8361524ff999"),
                Name = "Mobile Phones",
                CreateTime = DateTime.Now
            },
            new Category
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("f5a4eb59-26b3-4784-b427-65b5f7f57052"),
                Name = "Laptops",
                CreateTime = DateTime.Now
            }
            };
            builder.HasData(categories);
        }
    }

    public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

            builder.Property(p => p.Name)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Price)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.HasMany(p => p.Images)
                   .WithOne(p => p.Product)
                   .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            var products = new List<Product> {
             new Product
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("2cc1ca42-7f05-48e9-b223-886c5c98a4af"),
                Name = "IPhone 15 Pro",
                Description = "Titanum - 1TB",
                Price = 59.99,
                CategoryId = Guid.Parse("bdafc3c9-abe6-4ac5-bdb6-8361524ff999")
            },
            new Product
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("c8faaae7-fee5-450c-ac98-0baaa046077d"),
                Name = "IPhone 13",
                Description = "Moonlight - 128GB",
                Price = 29.99,
                CategoryId = Guid.Parse("bdafc3c9-abe6-4ac5-bdb6-8361524ff999")
            },
            new Product
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("e4b56b1a-6372-4e5b-9f61-03ee2b5e6b64"),
                Name = "MacBook Pro 16-inch",
                Description = "256GB SSD Storage / 8-Core CPU 8-Core GPU 8GB Unified Memory",
                Price = 1500.99,
                CategoryId = Guid.Parse("f5a4eb59-26b3-4784-b427-65b5f7f57052")
            },
            new Product
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("0d7957d2-2ca7-43eb-b9e0-6e300da1a6b4"),
                Name = "MacBook Air 13-inch",
                Description = "M3 Max / 1TB / 16-core CPU 40-core GPU 48GB Unified Memory",
                Price = 1350.99,
                CategoryId = Guid.Parse("f5a4eb59-26b3-4784-b427-65b5f7f57052")
            }
            };
            builder.HasData(products);
        }
    }


Even when using IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>, you still need to instruct the DbContext to apply these configurations. This is usually achieved in the DbContext class by calling the ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly method.
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Automatically applies all IEntityTypeConfiguration classes in the assembly
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

After registering the configurations in DbContext, run the migration to ensure that the data seeding is correctly reflected.

Your code looks good. But you need to write below code into your OnModelCreating method from DbContext.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Apply configurations to all IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> classes
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategoryConfiguration());  
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductConfiguration());        
}

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.applyconfiguration?view=efcore-8.0

That's so helpful thank you, worked well
